# Retrieve the Object values and assign it to Another one Object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, loops, object

I have to retrieve an object and assign it to another one. But in the new object, always the last item only stored.

I tried object.entries keys method but nothing worked.
code : https://codesandbox.io/s/k3p7j07x8o

```
let subject = {};
const obj = { a: 5, b: 4, c: 9 };
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
    //console.log(subject); // Here itself it's printing the last element
    subject.value = key;
    subject.text = value;
    console.log(subject.value + subject.text); // This showing the correct element
    console.log(subject); // This one showing the last elements
}
```

Comment: You are seeing the last value because the above code updates the `value` and `text` property of the same object. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
let subject = Object.assign({}, obj}
console.log(subject)
```

or

```
let subject = {};
Object.assign(subject, obj);
console.log(subject)
```